Getting 404 error while using axios-mock-adapter
I believe that i couldn'd configure the axios-mock-adapter. My files are:
axiosConfig.ts

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000', // Localhost
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
});

export default axiosInstance;

mockAxios.ts
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import axiosInstance from './axiosConfig';

const mockAxios = new MockAdapter(axiosInstance, { delayResponse: 200 });

// Mock responses
const projects = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Project 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Project 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Project 3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Project 4' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Project 5' },
];

mockAxios.onGet('/projects/fetchAll').reply(200, { data: projects });

export default mockAxios;

projectsApi.ts
import axios from 'axios';

const fetchAllProjects = async () => {
    console.log('Fetching all projects');
    const res = await axios.get('/projects/fetchAll');
    console.log(res);
    return res;
}

export { fetchAllProjects };

I tried to call it like const response = await fetchAllProjects();         console.log(response); but this call gets 404 error in projectsApi.ts file since it prints Fetching all projects but no res.
I don't know what else to do but I tried to use mockAxios.onAny() call. Other posts here didn't solve my issue.


You didn't use the configured axiosInstance.

You should call the API function after mocking.


e.g.
axiosConfig.ts:
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000', // Localhost
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
});

export default axiosInstance;

projectsApi.ts:
import axiosInstance from './axiosConfig';

const fetchAllProjects = async () => {
    console.log('Fetching all projects');
    const res = await axiosInstance.get('/projects/fetchAll');
    console.log(res.data);
    return res;
};

export { fetchAllProjects };

main.ts:
import './mockAxios';
import { fetchAllProjects } from './projectsApi';

function main() {
    fetchAllProjects();
}

main();

Execution result:
$ npx ts-node ./main.ts
Fetching all projects
{
  data: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Project 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Project 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Project 3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Project 4' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Project 5' }
  ]
}

